# Batch file to read multiple text lines in the text file

Tags: file, batch-file

I have a batch file.

```
set "firstLine="
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (input.txt) do (
  If not defined firstLine set "firstLine=%%A"
  set Lastline=%%A
)
REM *** FIRST CHECK ***
if "EOF" NEQ "%Lastline%" goto :fail

call :extractDate firstLineDate firstLine 
<file set /p line=
echo "%line%"
for /f "tokens=2 delims=|" %%# in ("%line%") do set "_date=%%#"
echo %_date%

call :convertToJulianDay julianFirstLine firstLineDate
REM GET MONTH, DAY, YEAR VALUES
FOR /F "TOKENS=1-3 DELIMS=/" %%A IN ("%1") DO SET MM=%%A& SET DD=%%B& SET YY=%%C
REM ELIMINATE LEFT ZEROS
SET /A DD=10%DD% %% 100, MM=10%MM% %% 100
REM CALCULATE JULIAN DAY NUMBER
IF %MM% LSS 3 SET /A MM+=12, YY-=1
SET /A A=YY/100, B=A/4, C=2-A+B, E=36525*(YY+4716)/100, F=306*(MM+1)/10, JDN=C+DD+E+F-1524

set "today=%date%"
call :convertToJulianDay julianToday today
REM GET MONTH, DAY, YEAR VALUES
FOR /F "TOKENS=1-3 DELIMS=/" %%A IN ("%1") DO SET MM=%%A& SET DD=%%B& SET YY=%%C
REM ELIMINATE LEFT ZEROS
SET /A DD=10%DD% %% 100, MM=10%MM% %% 100
REM CALCULATE JULIAN DAY NUMBER
IF %MM% LSS 3 SET /A MM+=12, YY-=1
SET /A A=YY/100, B=A/4, C=2-A+B, E=36525*(YY+4716)/100, F=306*(MM+1)/10, JDN=C+DD+E+F-1524

set /a diff=julianToday-julianFirstLine
REM *** SECOND CHECK ***
if %diff% NEQ 1 goto :fail
exit /b

:fail
echo File doesn't fit
```

And bellow is the sample input.txt

```
AML.DATA|01-JUN-2016
PORT_DATA|560538
NDB_AML_AA|43063
NDB_AML_LD|12878
NDB_AML_REPO|496
NDB_AML_TRAN|84596
NDB_AML_JOINT_AC|219873
NDB_AML_CUS_REL_PRTY|43
NDB_AML_BICCODE|108292
CUSTOMER_MASTER|684124
CATEGORY.MASTER|3288
DEPT.MASTER|2527
COUNTRY.MASTER|251
CUSTOMER.STATUS.MASTER|26
INDUSTRY.MASTER|65
JOB.TITLE.MASTER|22
COMPANY.MASTER|121
TRANSACTION.MASTER|3133
RELATION.MASTER|56
NDB_AML_TBILL_TBOND|2845
EOF
```

I want to modify my batch file to read the first line of the input.txt and if the date=sysdate-1 and the last line=EOF then proceed with the prog. But the bat file always say:

```
The system cannot find the batch label specified - extractDate
The system cannot find the file specified.
The system cannot find the batch label specified - convertToJulianDay
The system cannot find the batch label specified - convertToJulianDay
```

Comment: do those labels even exist?

Comment: Yes they do exist.

Comment: your errormessages clearly state, they don't.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the first line is simple.

```
If not defined firstLine set firstLine=%%A
```

Now you need to extract the date.
Then convert it to julian date.
Convert the system date to julian date,  too.
Compare the difference.

That's all

```
set "firstLine="
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (input.txt) do (
  If not defined firstLine set "firstLine=%%A"
  set Lastline=%%A
)
REM *** FIRST CHECK ***
if "EOF" NEQ "%Lastline%" goto :fail

call :extractDate firstLineDate firstLine 
call :convertToJulianDay julianFirstLine firstLineDate
set "today=%date%"
call :convertToJulianDay julianToday today

set /a diff=julianToday-julianFirstLine
REM *** SECOND CHECK ***
if %diff% NEQ 1 goto :fail
exit /b

:fail
echo File doesn't fit
```

Comment: I want to incorporate both checks, checking the date and the EOF flag at the last line. But I'm out of ideas to put both checks together. Looking forward to your comments.

Comment: @DeEDEe both checks are already incorporated in this answer. However, a much harder problem to solve is calculating Julian day. Have you noticed that's not given in the answer?

Comment: I didn't put it into the answer, as it's easy to find it with google

Comment: @jeb can you show me how to incorporate Julian day calculation?